# pandas Series getting 'Data must be 1-dimensional' error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm new to pandas & numpy. I'm running a simple program

```
labels = ['a','b','c','d','e'] 
s = Series(randn(5),index=labels)
print(s)
```

getting the following error

```
    s = Series(randn(5),index=labels)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 243, in
__init__
    raise_cast_failure=True)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2950, in
_sanitize_array
    raise Exception('Data must be 1-dimensional') Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Any idea what can be the issue? I'm trying this using eclipse, not using ipython notebook.

Comment: can you include your imports... just to make sure.  Because that looks like it should work.  I just ran your code with `from pandas import Series; 
from numpy.random import randn` and it worked just fine.

Comment: I was using from from numpy.matlib import randn. When I changed to numpy.random it worked...Thanks!!

Do you know if there is anyway I can make eclipse get the correct import?

Comment: I don't use eclipse, I have no clue.

Comment: Also, its always appreciated to upvote all answers that are useful and provide good information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you have your imports wrong.

If you add this to your code:

```
from pandas import Series
from numpy.random import randn

labels = ['a','b','c','d','e'] 
s = Series(randn(5),index=labels)
print(s)

a    0.895322
b    0.949709
c   -0.502680
d   -0.511937
e   -1.550810
dtype: float64
```

It runs fine.

That said, and as pointed out by @jezrael, it's better practice to import the modules rather than pollute the namespace.

Your code should look like this instead.

***solution***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

labels = ['a','b','c','d','e'] 
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5),index=labels)
print(s)
```

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure if generally is good solution use `from pandas import Series
from numpy.random import randn`. In my opinion is much better use  `import pandas as pd
import numpy as np`. What do you think?

Comment: @jezrael definitely!  This is simply identifying what the problem was.

Comment: Ok, so I think you can add it to answer - It works, but do not use it. ;)

Comment: @jezrael added, what's funny is that `from pandas import DataFrame, Series` is in Wes' book :-)

Comment: Yes, but [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html) it is - default pandas imports ;)

Comment: And your reference is far more recent sooo touche ;)

Comment: Hmmm, I am thinking if is better clearly add to answer - it works, but better is use another answer ;) I am not still clear what is the best

Comment: because OP starts `I'm new to pandas & numpy.` - So OP need many the best practices and `from pandas import Series
from numpy.random import randn` is not best practice (in my opinion, alhough Wes use it in his book). I sometimes thinking about my old bad answers how many people use it and unfortunately these my answers are poor ;(

Comment: I appreciate you looking out and advocating for the right thing.  Hopefully my edits satisfy.

Comment: Yes, no problem.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you need [`numpy.random.rand`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) for random `floats` or [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) for random `integers`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
labels = ['a','b','c','d','e'] 
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5),index=labels)
print(s)
a   -1.749765
b    0.342680
c    1.153036
d   -0.252436
e    0.981321
dtype: float64
```

---

```
np.random.seed(100)
labels = ['a','b','c','d','e'] 
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=5),index=labels)
print(s)
a    8
b    8
c    3
d    7
e    7
dtype: int32
```